# Database space issues with non English characters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am created a web app using Laravel and mysql. Most of the contents users put like stories, articles all are non English for which in database its taking a lot of space so that sometimes site got crashed also.

Is there any solution of storing non English characters with less space or same space as English characters.

Comment: when you create database choose encoding UTF-8

Comment: Yes done that but i am talking about the space which is consumed due to non english characters

Comment: what column type you used to save that characters?

Comment: when you save through Laravel (Eloquent) it will remove all multiple spaces.

Comment: @Hamza "logtext" for the column where non English characters will save.

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam its not about multiple spaces bro... If about the space means database memory

Comment: @John whats your column type?

Comment: To save space with UTF-8, use VARCHAR instead of logtext

Comment: But what for the Huge data!!!